# ¿Cómo cambiar título de consola en GNU/Linux con C++?

Tags: c++, linux, unix

Quiero una manera de poder establecer el título de las consolas en Linux
   de una manera similar a la que lo hago en Windows.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include<windows.h>
#else
    //
#endif

main(){
    #ifdef _WIN32
        SetConsoleTitle("El titulo de ventana en Windows");
    #else
        // Alguna función para cambiar el título para las terminales
    #endif

    // Programa...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 #ifdef _WIN32
    SetConsoleTitle("El titulo de ventana en Windows");
#else
    printf("\033]0;%s\007", "El titulo de ventana en Linux");
#endif
```

Actualmente utilizo esta función:

```
void nombre_ventana(string nombre){
    #ifdef _WIN32
    const char* n = nombre.c_str();
        SetConsoleTitle(n);
    #else
        char esc_start[] = { 0x1b, ']', '0', ';', 0 };
        char esc_end[] = { 0x07, 0 };
        cout << esc_start << nombre << esc_end;
    #endif
}
```

Comment: GRACIAS, pero seria posible algo asi para adaptarlo al ANSI? std::cout <<"\033]0;%s\007", "El titulo de ventana en Linux";

Comment: Actualmente utilizo una función. Lo podré en una edición de la respuesta actual.